# C# application crashes before start

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop

I come to you because I'm desperate. I've developed a GTK# application in C# with the latest MonoDevelop. It's built for .NET framework 4.0 / x86, and the only external library it uses is the official Mysql .Net connector. It's meant to run under Windows XP.

It's the first application I make with this IDE. I was very happy with the results and the development time, but the deployment is a real headache.

It works perfectly on the development machine. The debug is clean. Everything's okay.

Then, as I couldn't find any information about the deployment, I installed a clean XP to try it and see what do I should install on the client's machine.

I've installed the SP3, .NET 4.0 and copied the release package with all the DLLs mentioned in the build log (that made it work outside the MonoDevelop in the development machine). But I'm getting a "the application has encountered a problem and needs to close" error, with no exception, in kernel32.dll, offset 0012aeb.

I've tried to install the .NET 3.5 before the 4.0, updated IE (just in case...), copied more GTK# and Monodevelop DLLs to the exe's folder, installed the Mysql .NET connector, installed Mono 2.8... But nothing. Still getting that unexplained error.

Google and StackOverflow searches didn't help me. I've researched and tried a lot of things in the last twelve hours or more without moving from this machine.

Do you have any advice? What can be causing it? Is there any way to debug the exe (without installing VS...)? Does anyone know what are all the dependencies of this kind of executable?

Comment: if your run it from command line with a debug build, does it crash? if so, what is the stack?

Comment: As a really low-level test, surround the code in every method with a try-catch, and simply dump the exception stacktrace and message to a MessageBox.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast replies, everybody. I'm going to try this things and see what do I find out.

Comment: Running it from the console with --debug throws the same error and nothing in the console. I will try with try-catch and running it with debug and tracing. Thank you.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the advices and (again) fastest replies I've ever got in a forum :-) Trying to debug and edit/recompile I realized that .NET Framework 4.0 doesn't work if you don't have a previos version installed. So I just installed .NET 3.5 SP1. So, that with GTK# for .NET and the linked DLLs just copied into the exe folder makes this kind of apps work in Win XP. Warm regards!

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg can help you figuring some JIT trouble...

Even though it aint intuitive and require skills, Worth a try. might pop something up.

Answer (score 0):

If it's meant to run under Windows, then you should probably compile it with the Visual C# compiler.

However, more related to your problem - get a [debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugger) in your deployment machine and run the application on it. This is the best way to figure out the problem because we really can't guess it.

[Mono Application Deployment Guidelines](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Deployment)

Comment: Yes, I should have used VC#... The idea was to use free software. I had seen the guidelines, but as I can see they are for Linux. Gonna try a different debugger (the debugging inside Monodevelop throws no errors) and see what happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to installing Visual Studio on your production machine, one of them is the [Remote Debugging Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf8k2h6a.aspx). It does not require a Visual Studio installation. You can copy the files from your development machine to your server. I've got them under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger`.

You can also use it for [Remote Debugging of a Project Built Locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx).